# Using postgres json field with ember data

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, ember.js, ember-data

I've got a rails api that spits out a postgres field of type `json` called `colors`. I've got a series of input fields that can be changed and I'm hoping the keys on this json object can be modified when each field changes, but the binding doesn't seem to be working as expected.

The data looks like:

```
 "colors": { "primary_color": "#c43535", "secondary_color": "#0000FF" }
```

My inputs look like:

```
{{input type="text" class="form-control" value=model.colors.primary_color}}
{{input type="text" class="form-control" value=model.colors.secondary_color}}
```

This displays the correct color in the field, but when I update the field, the JSON object does not appear to be updated in the Ember Inspector.

[image: Color Pickers]

I've tried three different transforms so far:

**json.js**

```
export default DS.Transform.extend({

  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return JSON.parse(serialized);
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return JSON.stringify(deserialized);
  }

});
```

**raw.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({

  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }

});
```

**object.js**

```
export default DS.Transform.extend({

  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return Ember.isNone(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
  },

  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return Ember.isNone(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
  }

});
```

All *appear* to have the same result, that updating the fields does not modify the object. How do I serialize/bind/update a json object with ember-data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think. Serialize, means to make the object into a regular JSON object and deserialize, means to make it into a Ember object.

```
App.PrimaryColorTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  serialize: function(value) {
    return value.get('primary_color');
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return Ember.create({ primary_color: value[0]});
  }
});

App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
  primary_color: DS.attr('primaryColor'),

});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_creating-custom-transformations

Comment: Got me going in the right direction: https://gist.github.com/typeoneerror/ea854cfa9341f1388c37. I can see the values updating in Ember Inspector now. Not sure if I should JSON.stringify in `serialize` for saving to PSQL, exploring now.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I'm not sure if you need to JSON.stringify, I would think not, at least not here.

Answer (score 2):

By not specifying the type in `DS.attr()`, it just passes the raw object through, you can see that here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zitobi/2/edit

Comment: right, that works great for displaying the attributes, but the binding back to the object is not updated when changed.

Comment: What if you use this in your first transform: `Ember.Object.create(JSON.parse(serialized))`

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" :(

Comment: Seems like malformed JSON string passed to JSON.parse, @typeoneerror

Comment: Yeah, appears that way. I think Postgres json field is a json object like {primary: "#ff3300", secondary: "#0000FF"}, not a json string, so trying to parse might actually be unecessary since it's already an object. Investingating more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems to do the trick: https://gist.github.com/typeoneerror/ea854cfa9341f1388c37.